# Flutter Dynamic related dropdown list

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I have an api returning parent string children. I fill the level 0 with the children in the first dropdown.
when I select an element in the first dropdown, It should call the api to bring its' children and fill a new dropdown List and so on to the last child who has no children.
when I change any element on any level of dropdowns, It should remove all other dropdowns and call api to fill new dropdown children.
the code I write is:

```
//dropdown widget
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, camel_case_types, prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables

import 'package:cam_project/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DynamicWidget extends StatefulWidget {
// item is the dropdown elements,selectedValue is the value chosen to call api,onChangeElement it return the selected value to call the api
  final List<String> item;
  final String selectedValue;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChangeElement;

  DynamicWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.item,
    required this.selectedValue,
    required this.onChangeElement,
  });
  // Add a method to return the selected value
  @override
  State<DynamicWidget> createState() => _DynamicWidgetState();
}

class _DynamicWidgetState extends State<DynamicWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = '';
  List<String> item = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = widget.selectedValue;
      item = widget.item;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      item = widget.item;
    });
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      items: item.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.8,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                    color: kBlack, // Customize the color of the line
                    width: 1.0, // Customize the width of the line
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text(
                value,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
          widget.onChangeElement(
              dropdownValue); // Call the callback with the selected value
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
//the main widget 

class DisplayImagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic>? buildingUnitImages;
  final bool? isBuildingUnitImages;
  const DisplayImagesScreen(
      {super.key, this.buildingUnitImages, this.isBuildingUnitImages});

  @override
  State<DisplayImagesScreen> createState() => _DisplayImagesScreenState();
}

enum filter { all, company, building, category, project }

class _DisplayImagesScreenState extends State<DisplayImagesScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllImagesService();
  }

  List<dynamic> filteredImages = [];
  
  List<List<dynamic>> nestedListAllData = [];
  List<List<String>> nestedListArrayNames = [], nestedListArrayIds = [];
 
  void onSelectedValueChanged(String newSelectedValue) {
    setState(() {
      selectedBuildingUnitName = newSelectedValue;
    });
  }

 

  Future<void> getAllImagesService() async {
   //someCode
        nestedListAllData.add(getAllBuildings['data']);
        buildingUnitDataResponseNames.clear();
        for (var building in nestedListAllData[level]) {
          buildingUnitDataResponseNames.add(building['name']['en']);
          buildingUnitDataResponseIds.add(building['id']);
        }
        nestedListArrayNames.add(buildingUnitDataResponseNames);
        nestedListArrayIds.add(buildingUnitDataResponseIds);
        selectedBuildingUnitName = buildingUnitDataResponseNames[0];
        selectedBuildingUnitId = buildingUnitDataResponseIds[0];
      await updateBuildingOptions(
          nestedListArrayNames[0], selectedBuildingUnitName);
    }    }
    
  }

  Future<void> updateBuildingOptions(List<String> items, String value) async {
    setState(() {
      dynamicList.add(DynamicWidget(
          item: items,
          selectedValue: value,
          onChangeElement: onSelectedValueChanged));
    });
  }


// array for the dropdowns
  List<DynamicWidget> dynamicList = [];

// indicator of selected dropdown
  int dropDownIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget dynamicDropDown = GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      childAspectRatio: 4.5, // Adjust the aspect ratio to control the height
      children: [
        for (var dropdown in dynamicList)
          dropdown.item.isEmpty ? SizedBox() : dropdown,
      ],
    );

   
//code
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              AppLocalization.of(context)!
                  .getTranslatedValue("allImagesTitle")
                  .toString(),
            ),
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: kRed,
            //شريط الفلترة
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(appBarHeight),
              child: Expanded(
                child: Container(
//code
),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                          child: dynamicDropDown,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: kLightYellow,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: SafeArea(
//code          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
// on pressing this button it will created new dropdown and pass the //item to it with the initial selected value
              String selectedBuild = "";

              for (int i = 0; i < nestedListArrayNames.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nestedListArrayNames[i].length; j++) {
                  if (selectedBuildingUnitName == nestedListArrayNames[i][j]) {
                    selectedBuildingUnitId = nestedListArrayIds[i][j];
                    dropDownIndex = i;
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }

              //احضار ابناء العقدة المختارة
              var resultChildren =
                  await DIOServiceApi.getGetChildrenBuildingUnitService(
                      selectedBuildingUnitId, projectId);
              //احضار الصور التابعة للعقدة وكل ابناءها وعرض 3 صور فقط
              var result = await DIOServiceApi.getAllBuildingUnitImagesService(
                  selectedBuildingUnitId, projectId, true, 1, 10);
              print(result);
              setState(() {
                //اذا اخترنا من دروب قديمة يعمل حذف للعناصر الابناء
                if (dynamicList.length > 1 &&
                    dynamicList.length > dropDownIndex + 1) {
                  nestedListAllData.removeRange(
                      dropDownIndex + 1, nestedListAllData.length);
                  nestedListArrayNames.removeRange(
                      dropDownIndex + 1, nestedListArrayNames.length);
                  nestedListArrayIds.removeRange(
                      dropDownIndex + 1, nestedListArrayIds.length);
                  dynamicList.removeRange(
                      dropDownIndex + 1, dynamicList.length);
                }
                //اضافة الابناء الى المصفوفة الكلية
                nestedListAllData.add(resultChildren['data']);
                level = nestedListAllData.length - 1;
                //مصفوفات مساعدة
                List<String> buildingUnitChildrenNames = [];
                List<String> buildingUnitChildrenIds = [];
                for (var building in nestedListAllData[level]) {
                  buildingUnitChildrenNames.add(building['name']['en']);
                  buildingUnitChildrenIds.add(building['id']);
                }
                nestedListArrayNames.add(buildingUnitChildrenNames);
                nestedListArrayIds.add(buildingUnitChildrenIds);
                if (buildingUnitChildrenNames.isEmpty) {
                  selectedBuild = ''; // or any other default value like 'null'
                  selectedBuildingUnitId = '';
                } else {
                  selectedBuild = buildingUnitChildrenNames[0];
                  selectedBuildingUnitId = buildingUnitChildrenIds[0];
                }
                updateBuildingOptions(nestedListArrayNames[level], "");
              });
              filteredImages = [];
              filteredImages = (result['data'] is Map<String, dynamic>)
                  ? result['data'].values.toList()
                  : [];
              print('filteredImages');
              print(filteredImages);

              setState(() {
                imagesDataResponse.clear();
                selectedAll = filter.building;

                isFiltered = true;
                imagesDataResponse = filteredImages[1];
              });
            },
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I make an array of dynamicDropdown on each button click it add new dropdown with the children but the selectedValue gives an exception `Another exception was thrown: There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: .`
I pass null to the value in dropdown But, dropdown doesn't show the selected value any more.
please help.

Comment: Can you simplify your code and remove unnecessary things? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I did simplify the code .. and keep all the needed information.